# Grails build production by default in netbeans

Tags: grails, netbeans, build

I have been heavily using grails with netbeans for one of my projects, I at least deploy this project to prod environment 9-10 times a day and every once in a while (2-3 times a day) I create a war file configured for "Development" environment and I deploy it to my production server. This effectively brings down my service. 
To prevent this is there a way to configure my build file or netbeans so that when ever I make a build by right clicking on the project name I see a msgbox reminding me that build is geting made for Dev env?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommand to write your own cmd line scripts, which generate the war for the right env. e.g.

deploy_prod.bat script:

```
call grails prod war <name of war file>.war
```

on cmd line you can call the script by:

deploy_prod.bat

you can also use cmd line args to set the evn. e.g. deploy.bat prod

Comment: No ways of doing it from within Netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution from hitty5's response. I created a batch file in my NB project folder which runs grails prod ***-prod.war

Then from with my ide i have to right click on the file and select "Open in System" option and it will run the batch file:)
Thanks